# Vue Apollo auto refresh token implementation

Tags: vue.js, apollo, apollo-client, vue-cli, vue-apollo

I am trying to implement JWT auth to my SPA, login and logout are done, but i can`t figure out the proper (or just working) way to implement refresh token, any help will be appreciated!

I couldn`t find any tutorial about handling refresh token via Vue Appollo.
There is "[Vue CLI Apollo plugin](https://vue-cli-plugin-apollo.netlify.app/guide/configuration.html)" with

```
createApolloClient({
  ...
  // Custom pre-auth links
  // Useful if you want, for example, to set a custom middleware for refreshing an access token.
  preAuthLinks: [],
  ...})
```

But there are no example about implementing it, and looks like "Vue CLI Apollo plugin" is deprecated, it gets bo updates for a long time and doesn`t work with VUE CLI 4.

Current frontend stack is:

```
Vue-cli 4.5,
Apollo/client 3.5.8
Vue-apollo-option 4.0.0
Graphql 16.3.0
Vuex 4.0
```

My vue-apollo.js config:

```
import { createApolloProvider } from "@vue/apollo-option";
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from "@/constants/settings";

import {
  ApolloClient,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloLink,
} from "@apollo/client/core";

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
    },
  });

  return forward(operation);
});

const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql" });
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authMiddleware.concat(httpLink),
  cache,
});

export function createProvider() {   
  const apolloProvider = createApolloProvider({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
      },
    },
    errorHandler(error) {
      console.log("%Appollo error!", error.message);
    },
  });
  return apolloProvider;
}
```

So, right now a can login, store token, paste token with every request with help of **authMiddleware**, but where and how to implement refreshing of token? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Were you able to do it?